# why isn't Sendto() sending packet in c?

Tags: c, sockets, networking, tcp

I basically have create a simple program where it creates a custom UDP packet and send it to a destination IP address.

Here is the code UDPraw.c:

```
// ----rawudp.c------
// Must be run by root lol! Just datagram, no payload/data

#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/udp.h>

// The packet length
#define PCKT_LEN 8192

// Can create separate header file (.h) for all headers' structure
// The IP header's structure
struct ipheader {
    unsigned char      iph_ihl:5, iph_ver:4;
    unsigned char      iph_tos;
    unsigned short int iph_len;
    unsigned short int iph_ident;
    unsigned char      iph_flag;
    unsigned short int iph_offset;
    unsigned char      iph_ttl;
    unsigned char      iph_protocol;
    unsigned short int iph_chksum;
    unsigned int       iph_sourceip;
    unsigned int       iph_destip;
};

// UDP header's structure
struct udpheader {
    unsigned short int udph_srcport;
    unsigned short int udph_destport;
    unsigned short int udph_len;
    unsigned short int udph_chksum;
};

// total udp header length: 8 bytes (=64 bits)
// Function for checksum calculation. From the RFC,
// the checksum algorithm is:
//  "The checksum field is the 16 bit one's complement of the one's
//  complement sum of all 16 bit words in the header.  For purposes of
//  computing the checksum, the value of the checksum field is zero."
unsigned short csum(unsigned short *buf, int nwords)
{       //
unsigned long sum;
    for(sum=0; nwords>0; nwords--)
        sum += *buf++;
        sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum &0xffff);
        sum += (sum >> 16);
        return (unsigned short)(~sum);
    }

// Source IP, source port, target IP, target port from the command line arguments
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
int sd;

// No data/payload just datagram
char buffer[PCKT_LEN];

// Our own headers' structures
struct ipheader *ip = (struct ipheader *) buffer;
struct udpheader *udp = (struct udpheader *) (buffer + sizeof(struct ipheader));

// Source and destination addresses: IP and port
struct sockaddr_in sin, din;
int one = 1;
const int *val = &one;

memset(buffer, 0, PCKT_LEN);
if(argc != 5){
printf("- Invalid parameters!!!\n");
    printf("- Usage %s <source hostname/IP> <source port> <target hostname/IP> <target port>\n", argv[0]);
    exit(-1);
}

// Create a raw socket with UDP protocol
sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_UDP);
if(sd < 0){
perror("socket() error");

    // If something wrong just exit
    exit(-1);
} else
    printf("socket() - Using SOCK_RAW socket and UDP protocol is OK.\n");

// The source is redundant, may be used later if needed
// The address family
sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
din.sin_family = AF_INET;

// Port numbers
sin.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));
din.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[4]));

// IP addresses
sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);
din.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[3]);

// Fabricate the IP header or we can use the
// standard header structures but assign our own values.
ip->iph_ihl = 5;
ip->iph_ver = 4;
ip->iph_tos = 16; // Low delay
ip->iph_len = sizeof(struct ipheader) + sizeof(struct udpheader);
ip->iph_ident = htons(54321);
ip->iph_ttl = 64; // hops
ip->iph_protocol = 17; // UDP

// Source IP address, can use spoofed address here!!!
ip->iph_sourceip = inet_addr(argv[1]);

// The destination IP address
ip->iph_destip = inet_addr(argv[3]);

// Fabricate the UDP header. Source port number, redundant
udp->udph_srcport = htons(atoi(argv[2]));

// Destination port number
udp->udph_destport = htons(atoi(argv[4]));
udp->udph_len = htons(sizeof(struct udpheader));

// Calculate the checksum for integrity
ip->iph_chksum = csum((unsigned short *)buffer, sizeof(struct ipheader) + sizeof(struct udpheader));

// Inform the kernel do not fill up the packet structure. we will build our own...
if(setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, val, sizeof(one)) < 0){
    perror("setsockopt() error");
    exit(-1);
} else
    printf("setsockopt() is OK.\n");
    // Send loop, send for every 2 second for 100 count
    printf("Trying...\n");
    printf("Using raw socket and UDP protocol\n");
    printf("Using Source IP: %s port: %u, Target IP: %s port: %u.\n", argv[1], atoi(argv[2]), argv[3], atoi(argv[4]));

    int count;
    for(count = 1; count <=20; count++){
    if(sendto(sd, buffer, ip->iph_len, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(sin)) < 0){
        perror("sendto() error");
            exit(-1);
        } else {
        printf("Count #%u - sendto() is OK.\n", count);
        sleep(2);
    }
    }
    close(sd);
    return 0;
}
```

FYI: I am logged in as root user.

While compiling the code I just get these warnings saying:

```
custompacket.c: In function ‘main’:
custompacket.c:69:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘memset’ [enabled by default]
custompacket.c:73:9: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’ [enabled by default]
custompacket.c:82:9: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’ [enabled by default]
custompacket.c:128:6: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’ [enabled by default]
custompacket.c:139:20: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’ [enabled by default]
custompacket.c:143:10: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’ [enabled by default]
```

Other than that it compiles just fine.

Now what I basically do is to run the progam as `./rawtcp [source address] [source port] [destination address] [destination port]` also I have ran wireshark to sniff the packet but it doesn't show up. otherwise if I do a simple ping. ping echo requests and replies pop out in the wireshark.

I would really Appreciate if you could tell me what am I doing wrong here.
do I use `write()` other `sendto()` and how?

all replies are much much appreciated :)

Comment: Your question mentions TCP but your code is full of mentions of UDP. Which is it?

Comment: How do you expect this to be aligned : `unsigned char      iph_ihl:5, iph_ver:4;
    unsigned char      iph_tos;`  **?**

Comment: Add `#include <stdlib.h>` and `#include <string.h>` at the top to fix the warnings.  And compile with `-Wall -Werror`.

Comment: johnZwinck Yes i am running this as root and @cnicutar sry, I meant UDP.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I added the `stdlib.h` and `string.h` but when I add the parameter `-Wall -Werror` I am getting errors saying: `custompacket.c: In function ‘main’:
custompacket.c:98:5: error: implicit declaration of function ‘inet_addr’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
custompacket.c:67:29: error: variable ‘din’ set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors`

Comment: @Whoami: OK great, go one by one and fix each error until they're all fixed.

Comment: @Whoami Try adding the `netinet/in.h` and `arpa/inet.h` headers (from the man page for `inet_addr`).  As for `din`, did you intend to do something more with that variable?  It doesn't seem to get used after you fill out the struct with some data.  If not, you could remove `-Werror` for now, see what works, and update your question to remove the part about `memset` / `exit` / `strlen` warnings.

Comment: @CandyGumdrop I added the headers u said. still didnt worked.

Comment: @Whoami One more thing to clarify: can you please fix the formatting of the `csum` function?  Currently it's unclear what should and shouldn't be in the for loop.  Can you add an explicit `{` and `}` where you intend the enclosed body of the for loop to be?  And can you do the same for the body of the `else` towards the end, where you have `} else` followed by `printf("setSockopt() is OK.\n");`, but you have the indentation the same for following lines.

Comment: @JohnZwinck what I did to fix the error is that I removed `sin` and used `din` in my `sendto()` function. `sin` is basically for source address and source port and `din` is destination address and destination port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the warnings caused by missing headers are mostly irrelevant here, though it is always important to include the right header files to get correct function signatures, as doing otherwise can lead to much more subtle bugs when relying on the default implicit function declarations.

In your `struct ipheader`, there are a few problems.  Firstly, the bit field size of `iph_ihl` should be `4`, not `5`, as both the version and IHL fields of the IP header are 4 bits long.  This was probably just a typo.

Secondly, you include both `iph_flag` as 8 bits and `iph_offset` as 16 bits in your struct.  However, both of these fields should fit within the same 16 bits in the IP header.  The flags field should be 3 bits and the fragment offset field should be 13 bits.  Since in your code you leave these as their default zeroed values from `memset`, you can just remove the `flags` field completely from your struct and just have the 16 bit `iph_offset` field.

Another problem is with your usage of structs in general for this kind of byte-by-byte data packing.  C compilers are free to add any padding they like between the field of a struct for data alignment purposes.  So to use structs this way with any kind of reliability, you must rely on compiler-specific extensions, specifically `#pragma pack`, which is supported by GCC and Clang.

```
/* Set alignment of all fields in the struct to 1, to pack them as tightly as 
 * possible with no padding. */
#pragma pack(push, 1)

struct ipheader {
    /* ... */
};

struct udpheader {
    /* ... */
};

/* Reset back to normal. */
#pragma pack(pop)
```

It's worth noting that the exact behaviour of the alignment / padding of bit fields in structs is also implementation-defined, however it does work as intended for your program on my Linux machine with GCC, and is likely to work in a lot of setups.

Beyond this, there is another mistake on this line:

```
ip->iph_len = sizeof(struct ipheader) + sizeof(struct udpheader);
```

Like the other 16 bit fields in your header, you should set them with `htons()` to convert them to big-endian on little-endian machines:

```
ip->iph_len = htons(sizeof(struct ipheader) + sizeof(struct udpheader));
```

This is also the case for `iph_chksum`:

```
ip->iph_chksum = htons(csum((unsigned short *)buffer, sizeof(struct ipheader) + sizeof(struct udpheader)));
```

With these fixes, the packet does show in Wireshark as intended on my machine, however it may be worth noting that you do not set the UDP header's checksum.

An alternative to the struct approach for this would be to use an array of `unsigned char`, and then fill out the fields manually with bit shifting and other bit manipulation operations.  This way, you shouldn't even have to use `htons` to swap byte order as you will be manually filling in each byte anyway.  e.g.:

```
unsigned char ip_header[160];

ip_header[0] = ihl & (ip_ver << 4);

ip_header[2] = (unsigned char) (ip_len >> 8);
ip_header[3] = (unsigned char) (ip_len & 0xff);
```

Comment: Exactly, this is what I commented an hour ago. But the OP appears too lazy to read comments.

Comment: @CandyGumdrop Thank you so much for your reply, appreciate you that, but I still am moving my head around the code and trying to fix the mistakes I have made, but I couldn't fix it so far. can you please Post your working code that worked for you here? very much appreciate that.

Comment: @Whoami Here's a diff of what I changed to make it work: https://pastebin.com/0KVjdhUW  Here's the full code: https://pastebin.com/eWMyhSbz  If there's anything unclear in my answer, let me know and I'll update it.

Comment: @CandyGumdrop I just copied your full code and pasted  it in a new file named `customudp.c`, compiled it with `gcc -o customudp customudp.c` and ran it as `./customudp 192.168.1.152 1000 192.168.1.151 1000`. The IP that I ran the file from is at `192.168.1.152` and destination is `192.168.1.151`, and then I ran wireshark filtered packets with `(ip.src == 192.168.1.152 and ip.dst == 192.168.1.151) or udp.port == 1000` it still says `count # - Sendto() is OK.` as it used but no where in the wireshark it pops up.

Comment: @Whoami Does it work if you change it to use `din` instead of `sin`?  I was testing with both source and dest as `127.0.0.1` which might explain why it worked for me.  If it works, I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: @candyGumdrop brah, It just worked, and you know how it feels when ur code finally works, thanks man appreciate that. and one more thing. When I changed `sin` to `din` I also had to change the program parameter localization from source to destination I mean: `./customudp DestinationIP port SourceIP port`, and It finally worked showing in wireshark saying: `Destination Unreachable (port unreacheable)` thx

Comment: @CandyGumdrop sry for bothering again, but can you plz have a look at this now? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48338190/sending-custom-tcp-packet-using-sendto-in-c  very much appreciate for that brah

Answer (score 0):

The solution, indirectly, was to enable compiler warnings `-Wall -Werror`.  This immediately told you that `din` was never used, and that variable was supposed to be the destination address.  You had used `sin` (source address) by mistake in the `sendto()` call.

You should always develop code using `-Wall -Werror` (and perhaps more, like `-Wextra` if your compiler and code allow it).

Comment: While this does fix warnings, this doesn't fix the intended behaviour of the program.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing includes.

To fix it, please add:

```
 #include <string.h>  -> for memset, strlen
 #include <stdlib.h>  -> for exit
```